# redux action is not a promise thus cannot use .then method

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

when my `props.postToAllData` and `props.postToUserData` methods are called, it takes a while for the fetch method to make its course. Thus, I am being pushed to another webpage and the new information doesn't show since Im pushing to a new page quicker than my post method. I cant use `.then` method since this isn't a promise. What can i do to push to after the post method finishes?

```
const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (ingredientsArray.length !== 0 && instructionsArray.length !== 0) {
      props.postToAllData(
        {
          ...recipe,
          ingredients: ingredientsArray,
          instructions: instructionsArray,
          img: isSelectedFile,
          author: user.username,
        },
      ),
      props.postToUserData(
        {
          ...recipe,
          ingredients: ingredientsArray,
          instructions: instructionsArray,
          img: isSelectedFile,
          author: user.username,
        },
      ),
      resetForm();
      history.push('/dashboard/global');
    } else setErrorForm('Please fill in all fields');
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a middleware for redux called [thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk). Thunk allows you to write async actions, which you can't with regular redux.

It'll work like this:

**Declare an async action with your api call**

```
const myAsyncAtion = () => {
    return async () => {
      const response = await apiCall();
      return response;
    }
}
```

And just dispatch it in your code like any other action. Now it returns a promise, which you can chain with `.then` or `await`. Cheers!

```
  const save = async () => {
      await props.myAsyncAction();
      console.log('hooray')
      // or

      props.myAsyncAction().then(() => console.log('hooray'))

  }
```